# Inherit from an abstract base with a more specific method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, overriding

Lots of questions with these keywords; I sifted through the first 30 or so then gave up.

I have interfaces like so:

```
public interface IColumnRule
{
    int Length { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Parse(string toParse);
    int Position { get; set; }
    Type Type { get; }
}

public interface IColumnRule<T> : IColumnRule
{
    ColumnRule<T>.RuleFluentInterface<T> Configure { get; }
    new T Parse(string rowdata);
    Func<string, T> ParsingFunction { get; set; }
}
```

... the idea being, one would implement the `IColumnRule<T>` to create a strongly-typed column parser utilizing the `Func<string, T>`.

The problem is, I store these `IColumnRule<T>` concretes in an `IList<IColumnRule>` container.  There are multiple types of `IColumnRule<T>`, each implementing on a different type.  When I invoke the `Parse` method on the `IColumnRule` interface, I am expecting the `new Parse(string)` method of the subclass to be called, but the base `Parse` is the one actually being called.

How can I invoke the subclass generic `T Parse(string)` method from a collection of `IColumnRule` using the interface's `object Parse(string)` ... or is this impossible?

Comment: This is expressly the behavior you get when declaring a `new` function.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You had your implementation details in your question just a few minutes ago but removed them. That helped to explain why you were having an issue. I've updated my answer with a more detailed solution that should help you.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yeah I decided it was too much information and would be a TL;DR kinda thing.  Your answer was what I was looking for; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `IColumnRule<T>` would have to provide a compliant `Parse` method. Given your code, the easiest way to do that is with an protected abstract method in your base class which is overridden in your subclass.

```
public abstract class ColumnRule : IColumnRule
{
    ...

    public object Parse(string rowdata)
    {
        return this.ParseInternal(rowdata);
    }

    protected abstract object ParseInternal(rowdata);
}

public class ColumnRule<T> : ColumnRule, IColumnRule<T>
{
    ...

    public new T Parse(string rowdata)
    {
        // strong-typed parse method
    }

    protected override object ParseInternal(string rowdata)
    {
        return this.Parse(rowdata); // invokes strong-typed method
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs You can create a collection of `IColumnRule` just fine, and easily do `rulesCollection.Select(r => r.Parse(rowdata))`

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> When I invoke the Parse method on the IColumnRule interface, I am expecting the new Parse(string) method of the subclass to be called, but the base Parse is the one actually being called.

Yes, it would. You've got two methods which are *unrelated* as far as the type system, CLR and compiler are concerned.

> How can I invoke the subclass generic T Parse(string) method from a collection of IColumnRule using the interface's object Parse(string) ... or is this impossible?

The simplest approach would be to have an abstract class implementing this as:

```
public abstract ColumnRuleBase<T> : IColumnRule<T>
{
    public object Parse(string toParse)
    {
        IColumnRule<T> genericThis = this;
        return genericThis.Parse(toParse);
    }

    ...
}
```

(If you had the two method names being different, it would be slightly simpler.)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know the type somehow:

```
List<IColumnRule> rules;  // populated from somewhere

foreach (IColumRule<int> rule in rules.OfType<IColumnRule<int>>()) {
    int foo = rule.Parse(rowData);
}
```

Or just cast a known element:

```
int foo = ((IColumnRule<int>)rules[5]).Parse(rowData);
```